# Cannot send mails to hotmail on win 8.1

Tags: c#, email, windows-8.1

I am tyring to send an email form an hotmail account using c#.

This is the code:

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials =  false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName@hotmail.com" , "password");
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.live.com";
        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.SendCompleted += SmtpClientSendCompleted;
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage("userName@hotmail.com", "me@gmail.com", "The subject", "The body");

        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occur while sending the mail: {0}", ex.Message));                
            return;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Message was sent succesfully\n");

    }
```

This code works perfectly on Win8 and Win7 but fails on win8.1 and throw the following Exception:

> **System.IO.IOException**: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)

Also, if I cahnge the mail provider to gmail.com it also works perfectly.

I tries to send a mail from hotmail account on win8.1 using ThunderBird and it worked.

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Does it throw an exception when sending throw win8.1?

Comment: What does "it fails" mean? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error message? You need to provide information we can use to try and help; "it fails" might be clear to you, but we can't see your screen or read your mind from here.

Comment: @KenWhite You are right. i added the exception description.

Answer (score 0):

This is presumably a problem with Windows 8.1 (preview). Several users have already reported this issue on the [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5555297a-3b32-41f4-aedf-666825a9f0c0/cant-send-email-to-hotmail-on-windows-81-os) and [TechNet forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/023d7598-9311-4b84-b1df-81ceda011fe4/bug-smtplivecom-stopped-working-after-win-81-tested-ol2013-win8-my-lan-roaming-user).

If you're developing an ASP.NET application, this is probably not a problem, since you'll be running your production build on environment that are yet to be on 8.1.

An alternative solution is to switch to a different SMTP service, some users has report that Gmail's SMTP is working fine with 8.1 preview.